# ValueError and OSError when attempting to install and run Stable Diffusion

Tags: artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, miniconda, stable-diffusion

Was attempting to install and run Stable Diffusion on my local machine via [these instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/830179/how-to-run-stable-diffusion-on-your-pc-to-generate-ai-images/). Got to the section where I'm testing out the model to see if it runs and I get this:

```
(ldm) C:\stable-diffusion\stable-diffusion-main>python scripts/txt2img.py --prompt "a close-up portrait of a cat by pablo picasso, vivid, abstract art, colorful, vibrant" --plms --n_iter 5 --n_samples 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alditrus\.conda\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\transformers\feature_extraction_utils.py", line 403, in get_feature_extractor_dict
    resolved_feature_extractor_file = cached_path(
  File "C:\Users\alditrus\.conda\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\hub.py", line 282, in cached_path
    output_path = get_from_cache(
  File "C:\Users\alditrus\.conda\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\hub.py", line 545, in get_from_cache
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 28, in <module>
    safety_feature_extractor = AutoFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(safety_model_id)
  File "C:\Users\alditrus\.conda\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\feature_extraction_auto.py", line 270, in from_pretrained
    config_dict, _ = FeatureExtractionMixin.get_feature_extractor_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alditrus\.conda\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\transformers\feature_extraction_utils.py", line 436, in get_feature_extractor_dict
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this model, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like CompVis/stable-diffusion-safety-checker is not the path to a directory containing a preprocessor_config.json file.
Checkout your internet connection or see how to run the library in offline mode at 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.
```

Not sure what could be causing this as I have limited coding experience. Checked my internet connection and it runs just fine. Is the tutorial outdated or is something else going on?

I'm running this on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: I just added that tag because the tutorial requires you to install git first. I could remove the tag if it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

From what I hear, it can get complicated. Do you need to run locally or are you just trying to use? If you're just trying play with it, consider something like https://www.thinkdiffusion.com which serves up stable diffusion with a1111 or vlad UIs for cheap.